# jQuery: add div if it does not exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to addClass if it does not exist e.g.

```
$("ul:not([class~='bbox'])").addClass("bbox");
```

Or

```
if(!$("ul").hasClass("class-name")){
    $("ul").addClass("bbox");
 }
```

But how do I check if `ul` element itself with a class already exist and if `ul` doesn't exist then add one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You check the [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/).

Ex:

```
if( $("ul.class-name").length ){
    //do something
}
```

If there are no matches, length will be zero and thus false (or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)), otherwise it will be true (or [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy))